# Cannot change physical location of Default IIS Website on Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: iis, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to become familiar with IIS using WIndows Server 2012R2. I started by trying to move the default Website from `C:\inetpub\wwwroot` to `C:\sample`. In the Website Advanced Settings I modified the Physical Path, restarted IIS and cleared the browser cache (Chrome).  However, when I try to bring up the website again `http://127.0.0.1/` I get this error:

> HTTP Error 404.3 - Not Found

It worked fine before I moved the website location. Is there something else I need to do? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis Enable FRT and read it.

Comment: It turns out that I had to enable ASP which apparently is not enabled by default on Server 2012.  Hopefully this information helps some other readers.

Comment: Then you should post your answer and accept it.